# String similarity between two list in R (stringsim)

Tags: r

I'm using stringsim to compare all the names of two lists, and I want to know for each name in x2, who from the list x1 is the one with the highest string similarity (the name and the number of similarity)

```
library(stringdist)
library(data.table)

a= data.frame(x1=c("RODRIGO ENRIQUE SANCHEZ TORRES", "MOISES AVELARDO HERRERA", "ALBERTA REDOBLE AVENDAÑO", "JAVIERA IGNACIA DOMINGUEZ FIGUEROA "))

x2=c("RODRIGO MANRIQUEZ MANRIQUEZ", "MOISES AVELARDO HERRERA","JESUS FIGUEROA", "ALFREDO MARIN OSSA")

sapply(a$x1, function(x){stringsim(x,x2,method='jw')})

          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 0.7608025 0.5781190 0.5007015 0.6373898
[2,] 0.6313441 1.0000000 0.6416063 0.5386128
[3,] 0.5325397 0.5299057 0.4206349 0.5166667
[4,] 0.6159544 0.7062802 0.6136040 0.5587302
```

I want something like that

```
Name                              percentage     best_match
RODRIGO ENRIQUE SANCHEZ TORRES    0.7608025      RODRIGO MANRIQUEZ MANRIQUEZ
MOISES AVELARDO HERRERA           1.0000000      MOISES AVELARDO HERRERA
```

Comment: You can select the index of max value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than iterate over the names, you can use `stringdistmatrix()` which should be faster as the number of comparisons made grows. Then you just need to use indexing to build the results:

```
library(stringdist)

distmat <- 1 - stringdistmatrix(a$x1, x2, method='jw')
idx <- max.col(distmat)
data.frame(name = a$x1, nearest =  x2[idx], score = distmat[cbind(seq_along(a$x1), idx)])

                                 name                     nearest     score
1      RODRIGO ENRIQUE SANCHEZ TORRES RODRIGO MANRIQUEZ MANRIQUEZ 0.7608025
2             MOISES AVELARDO HERRERA     MOISES AVELARDO HERRERA 1.0000000
3            ALBERTA REDOBLE AVENDAÑO     MOISES AVELARDO HERRERA 0.6416063
4 JAVIERA IGNACIA DOMINGUEZ FIGUEROA  RODRIGO MANRIQUEZ MANRIQUEZ 0.6373898
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helps me a lot

Answer (score 0):

An option is to get the index of the `max` value to extract the matching element from  'a2' and `rbind` the `list` elements

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(a$x1, function(x) {
     v1 <- stringsim(x,x2,method='jw')
    data.frame(Name = x, percentage = max(v1),
            best_match = x2[which.max(v1)])
 }))
#                                 Name percentage                  best_match
#1      RODRIGO ENRIQUE SANCHEZ TORRES  0.7608025 RODRIGO MANRIQUEZ MANRIQUEZ
#2             MOISES AVELARDO HERRERA  1.0000000     MOISES AVELARDO HERRERA
#3            ALBERTA REDOBLE AVENDAÑO  0.6416063     MOISES AVELARDO HERRERA
#4 JAVIERA IGNACIA DOMINGUEZ FIGUEROA   0.6373898 RODRIGO MANRIQUEZ MANRIQUEZ
```

---

Or another option is `outer` and vectorized `rowMaxs` with `max.col`

```
library(matrixStats)
m1 <- outer(a$x1, x2, FUN = stringsim, method = 'jw')
data.frame(Name = a$x1, percentage = rowMaxs(m1), 
       best_match =  x2[max.col(m1, 'first')])
#                                 Name percentage                  best_match
#1      RODRIGO ENRIQUE SANCHEZ TORRES  0.7608025 RODRIGO MANRIQUEZ MANRIQUEZ
#2             MOISES AVELARDO HERRERA  1.0000000     MOISES AVELARDO HERRERA
#3            ALBERTA REDOBLE AVENDAÑO  0.6416063     MOISES AVELARDO HERRERA
#4 JAVIERA IGNACIA DOMINGUEZ FIGUEROA   0.6373898 RODRIGO MANRIQUEZ MANRIQUEZ
```